# Unpredictable Boot Failure of Dell 2950 II

Tags: debian-wheezy, dell-poweredge

We recently purchased a refurbished Dell 2950 II to use as a development box in our lab.

After installing the OS (Debian Wheezy) and booting for the first time, I received the following errors in the DRAC, and the host reboots unexpectedly:

```
Critical    08/09/2014 03:13:50 CPU 2 has an internal error (IERR).
Critical    08/09/2014 03:13:50 CPU 1 has an internal error (IERR).
```

After that, I receive the following over the course of the next boot (in reverse order):

```
Critical    08/09/2014 03:15:41 A fatal IO error detected on a component at 
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:41 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:41 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:41 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:41 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:41 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:40 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
Non-Recoverable 08/09/2014 03:15:40 CPU 2 machine check detected.
Non-Recoverable 08/09/2014 03:15:40 CPU 2 machine check detected.
Critical    08/09/2014 03:15:40 A fatal IO error detected on a component at 
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:40 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
Critical    08/09/2014 03:15:40 A fatal IO error detected on a component at 
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:40 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:40 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:40 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:40 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:40 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
OK  08/09/2014 03:15:40 An OEM diagnostic event has occurred.
Non-Recoverable 08/09/2014 03:15:39 CPU 1 machine check detected.
OK  08/09/2014 03:14:05 CPU 1 is operating correctly.
OK  08/09/2014 03:14:05 CPU 2 is operating correctly.
OK  08/09/2014 03:14:05 CPU 1 is operating correctly.
```

Now, what's odd is that about 75% of the time, it will fail to boot and displays the errors above, and the other 25% it boots fine.

The reboot always happens following the GRUB menu, but before Debian begins posting the typical syslog/boot messages.

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Start with the basics. Make sure the processors and memory sticks are seated securely.

Comment: @joeqwerty This is the first thing I do as a matter of course, but it didn't help this time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the framebuffer in your GRUB settings.  You can add a "nofb" to the end of your boot string.  We ran into this exact problem on either a Dell 2950 II or III.

Comment: I don't want to sound too optimistic, but after adding the `nofb` option to GRUB, I haven't had it reboot itself once yet.  I rebooted several times, several different ways to give it the best chance to crash, and it didn't.  So that's a good sign.

Comment: It hasn't crashed again yet...  I'm choosing this as the answer.  Thanks!